# Find out from C# Code behind what is the active Jquery tab index

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, tabs

I have two aspx buttons on two separate Jquery tab panels.  I'd like to get the index of the active Jquery tab from the c# code behind so that the button within that tab becomes invisible. Any help will be greatly appreciated. ASP:

```
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenFGetActiveTab" runat="server"/>
            <button ID="btnGetActiveTab"></button>
            <div id="tabs">
            <ul>        
            <li><a href="#tabs-1"></a></li>        
            <li><a href="#tabs-2"></a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="tabs-1" style="border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanelSearchCustomer" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <contentTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="btnCustSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" ToolTip="Click to Search" OnClick="btnCustSearch_Click" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnAddCustomer" runat="server" Text="Add New" CommandName="insert" Visible="True" ToolTip="Add to Workbasket" OnClick="addToWorkBasket_Click" />
            <asp:GridView ID="gridCustSearch" OnRowCreated="gridCustLicSearch_RowCreated runat="server"></asp:GridView>
            </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>                 
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-2" style="border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;">
            <asp:Button ID="btnSearchLicense" runat="server" Text="Search" ToolTip="Click to Search" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnAddLicense" runat="server" Text="Add to Workbasket" Visible="False" ToolTip="Add to Workbasket" OnClick="btnAddLicense_Click" />
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanelLicenseSearchFields" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:GridView ID="gridLicSearch" runat="server" OnRowCreated="gridCustLicSearch_RowCreated"></asp:GridView>
            </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div>
            </div>
```

JQUERY:

```
                <link href="../css/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
            <script src="../js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
            <script src="../js/reflection.js"></script>
            <script src="../js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">


            $(document).ready(function () {


            $(function () {
            $("#tabs").tabs({ event: "click" });

            });

            $('#btnGetActiveTab').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            varTab = $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected");
            document.getElementById("<%= hiddenFGetActiveTab.ClientID %>").value = varTab;
            //$("#hiddenFGetActiveTab").val(varTab);
            //alert(varTab);
            alert(document.getElementById("<%= hiddenFGetActiveTab.ClientID %>").value);
            });

            function tabChanged(tabIndex) {
            varTab = $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected");
            $("#hiddenFGetActiveTab").val(varTab);
            alert(document.getElementById("<%= hiddenFGetActiveTab.ClientID %>").value);
            }
            });
```

C# Code Behind:

```
                protected void gridCustLicSearch_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
            if (activeTabIndex == Tab-1)
            {
            //Make First button visible
            //do other stuff


            }
            else if (activeTab == Tab-2)
            {   
            //Make Second button visible
            //do other stuff

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing any of your code, I'd recommend using a `<asp:HiddenField`...
Whenever you change a tab, set the hidden field to the index of the current tab.

Then, in the codebehind you can see which tab is currently selected and enable/disable things as you wish...

Short Example:
In your aspx page add the following:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnField" runat="server" />
```

When you change tabs (in Javascript):

```
function tabChanged(tabIndex)
{
    $("#hdnField").val(tabIndex);
}
```

In CodeBehind:

```
if (hdnField.Value == "1")
   ....
```

Comment: @KerwinLondono Please add the markup to your original question

Comment: Thank you but how do I call function tabChanged(tabIndex)? I can change the value of the hidden field with a button click but can't figure our how to do it when the tab is selected.  Thank you.

Comment: Code behind:    protected void gridCustLicSearch_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
      AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel activeTab = TabContainerSearch.ActiveTab;
            if (activeTabIndex == Tab-1)
            {
     //Make First button visible
     //do other stuff
   
               
            }
            else if (activeTab == TabPanelCustomer)
            { 
    //Make Second button visible
     //do other stuff
               
            }

Comment: Asp Mark-up:    <div id="tabs">
<ul>        
<li><a href="#tabs-1">Step 1</a></li>        
<li><a href="#tabs-2">Step 2</a></li> 
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
"First GridView is Here" "First ASP Button is Here - Invisible"
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
"Second GridView is Here"
"Second ASP Button is Here - Invisible"</div>
                    </div>

Comment: JQUERY JS:$('#btnGetActiveTab').click(function (event) {
event.preventDefault();
varTab = $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected");
document.getElementById("<%= hiddenFGetActiveTab.ClientID %>").value = varTab;
alert(document.getElementById("<%= hiddenFGetActiveTab.ClientID %>").value);  });
function tabChanged(tabIndex) {
varTab = $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected");
$("#hiddenFGetActiveTab").val(varTab);
alert(document.getElementById("<%= hiddenFGetActiveTab.ClientID %>").value);
            }

Comment: I have a button named btnGetActiveTab and a hideden field named hiddenFGetActiveTab.  I'm new to stack overflow and didn't like the way the code came out.  I'll try to repost in blocks.  Thank you.

Comment: Please add the code to your original question, I cant really understand it when its in the comments..

Comment: Ok. So what is the value of hiddenFGetActiveTab in CodeBehind?

Comment: hiddenFGetActiveTab is showing the correct tab index on code behind but it relies on the btnGetActiveTab button click event on the client side (I click on the btnGetActiveTab button first, then I click on a second asp runat server button to execute the code behind).  How can I call a function that does the same thing as the button click each time a tab is selected? Thank you!

Comment: You can use the [__doPostBack](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/320_Doing_or_Raising_Postback_using___doPostBack%28%29_function_from_Javascript_in_AspNet.aspx) function

Comment: Thanks. I managed to work around my issue above by simply calling a different method on each onrowcreated event for each gridview situated within each tab.  It's duplicate code but I just needed to move on.  The _doPostBack function is something I will definitely need as I am employing jquery client and asp server side invocations.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be of help
http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate

If you can handle the tab activation event, you can set an Hidden field with the state, or to make an Ajax call to the server to send the data to a server session.

Another way may be, when you make the post, to check the Active option
http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active
  to add the index to the posted data.

Answer (score 0):

Guess `ui.newTab.index()` would do the trick.

Do check the tab index and set visibilty for your button accordingly.

For instance like,

```
document.getElementById('<%=Button1.ClientID%>').style.display = 'block'
```

You dont have to go server side for that.